# Biopython cannot export numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, macos-monterey

I am trying to use Biopython using anaconda and the Jupiter notebook with Python3.

However, simply import numpy gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py:23, in <module>
     22 try:
---> 23     from . import multiarray
     24 except ImportError as exc:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py:10, in <module>
      9 import functools
---> 10 from . import overrides
     11 from . import _multiarray_umath

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py:6, in <module>
      4 import os
----> 6 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      7     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)
      8 from numpy.compat._inspect import getargspec

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <module>
----> 1 import numpy

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:144, in <module>
    141 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
    142 from . import _distributor_init
--> 144 from . import core
    145 from .core import *
    146 from . import compat

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py:49, in <module>
     25     import sys
     26     msg = """
     27 
     28 IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
   (...)
     47 """ % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.executable,
     48         __version__, exc)
---> 49     raise ImportError(msg)
     50 finally:
     51     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

I have tried everything I know:

- Unsintall and install numpy again.
- I did the same for Biopython.
- I am working on my created and activated environment called dissertation.
- I have checked the not useful website for numpy but nothing seems to be working for Mac OS and Jupiter Notebook.
- I have checked that Python, anaconda, Biopython and numpy are all updated.
- I even uninstalled and installed anaconda.

Any idea what's causing this problem? I AM USING macOS Monterey version 12.1 with the Apple M1.

Comment: How did you install numpy?  As the error message suggests, it looks like you have installed a version that's not the right one for your computer.

Comment: I have installed it differently to see if that works: Conda install numpy, pip3 install numpy and using Conda environment navigation and selecting Biopython. As Biopython requires numpy, it installs that as well. On the three different occasions, I've tried to uninstall and install... so I'm lost as to what try next